# Webpack plugin: Catch errors in build process

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to write a plugin that hooks into various webpack events.. I can't get the plugin to hook into the failed-module event. build-module and succeed-module work fine.

Basically I want to catch any errors that occur during the build process and report them to some external thing. (I'm writing a plugin that emits some signals to an external process when webpack compile process starts, ends or raises errors).

```js
Plugin.prototype.apply = function(compiler) {
    var self = this;

    compiler.plugin('compilation', function(compilation, callback) {

      compilation.plugin('build-module', function(){
        self.shout('build module');
      });

      compilation.plugin('succeed-module', function(){
        self.shout('succeed module');
      });

      compilation.plugin('failed-module', function(){
        self.shout('failed module');
      });
    });

    compiler.plugin('compile', function(compiler, callback) {
      self.shout('started');
    });

    compiler.plugin('emit', function(compiler, callback) {
      self.shout('done');
      callback();
    });
};
```

All but failed-module hooks work. To test, I add a syntax or import error to one of my js files. webpack reports the error on console but the hook is never called. Every other hook but failed-module is called as expected. How do I catch errors in the build process?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your syntax error is actually causing a failed-module.  This simple test with a jsx module shows that the webpack module build process ignores a simple syntax error (with babel), but can't ignore issues when jsx is not transpiled.

```
var React = require('react');

//here's the syntax error
asdf

var FrontPage = React.createClass({
    displayName: 'FrontPage',
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="FrontPage">
            </div>
        );
    }
});
module.exports = FrontPage;
```

Using your plugin with jsx modules, here's the config that absorbs the error:

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        loaders: ['babel']
    }]
}
```

`no errors`

and here's the config that triggers the failed-module

```
module: {
    loaders: [{
        test: /\.jsxz$/,
        loaders: ['babel']
    }]
}
```

`ModuleParseError: Module parse failed: ...`

Honestly, I'm not sure why it doesn't fail on simple syntax error, perhaps by design?  I would post an issue to the webpack [repo](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues).